# Android: there's no way i can install admob on my app

Tags: android, admob

I begin to get angry, there's no way I can put admob in my app.

I have a **2.3.3** app with **min-sdk="10"** I need it for zxing.

now I need to put admob... I go in my account to download it (version 6.0.1), and i found that android 3.2 is needed!

I've tried various implementation, such as put admob4, varios code, but i had no success...
how can i install admob and let 2.3.3? how can make this terrible thing work?

logcat:

07-10 13:55:20.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1348): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.mi.action.codmmunicator_2ddecoder/it.mi.action.codmmunicator_2ddecoder.Tabs}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView

Comment: you simply need to go `Right click on your project` > `properties` > `Android` > `check on 3.2` , it wont hurt your project in anyways.

Comment: i don't ahve a 3.2, and i can't find in install packages

Comment: if you dont have it there are two options, either get the older version of the `ADMOB SDK`(which is rare to be found and not recommended), or update your `Android SDK` and install the `3.2` SDK

Comment: the app crash always, with various code and various jar.
it's impossible!

Comment: Let me tell you, integrating Admob is the most simple Adnetwork integration you would come across in Android

Comment: yeah yeah, i know, i've done it a lot of times, but in this app is literally impossible.

Comment: i've tried also with 4.1.1 with no result. i've added the logcat

Comment: maybe the problem is because i use tabs?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13677/discussion-between-zak-and-some-one-some-where)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.ro/2012/06/android-how-to-add-admob-to-android-in.html) you can see how you can add admob into your app. You simply have to work with the 3.2 or 4 android sdk but in your manifest min-sdk tag you put 10 ... For more details please take a look at that tutorial.